# SAPUI5 VizFrame: How to get the selected data points

Tags: sapui5

I used a VizFrame to display data in my project.
The normal behaviour of the VizFrame when you select data in the graph you see a popover with the data of the selected point. When you select more than one point the content of the popover is something like in the screenshot: [popover content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFaYX.png).
I tried using attaching myself to the SelectedData Event. The oControlEvent.mParameters contain the data nodes being currently selected for THAT event.

For example: I click node A => the node A is in the oControlEvent.mParameters. => OK

Then I click additionally on node B (so node A and B are selected) => only the node B is contained in the oControlEvent.mParameters. => not OK.

What I need is the set of all nodes that are currently selected in the graph, not just the one that triggered the event.

This information must be contained somewhere, as the Tooltip correctly shows "2 data nodes selected" after the user clicked B.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `oControlEvent.mParameters.data`, or `oControlEvent.getParameter('data')` will (correctly) only contain the elements that actually triggered the event. (may be more than one data point if you select several data points in one go by dragging a rectangular area over the data points)

if you need all currently selected data points, use `oControlEvent.getSource().vizSelection()` (here, `getSource()` will return the vizFrame)

Cheers, iPirat